# Eclipse '@Override' issues when switching from Mac to PC

Tags: android, eclipse, interface, overriding

Ok, so I'm far from an expert developer, as you'll soon find out, but I've had this odd problem when cloning code to my pc. I'm working on an Android app and I use a git repository on bitbucket...my issue is that one of my classes implements an interface with several required methods that use the @Override annotation. Now I am also working on both a mac and pc and whenever I have to reclone into my pc workspace (which is more often than you'd think) I get an error that says that the overriding methods "must override a superclass method" and suggests that I remove them. To my understanding they are overriding methods and do it fine on my macbook but when i switch over to my pc the @Override annotations have to be removed each time in order for eclipse to not have a hissyfit.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

If it helps, the interface I'm implementing is TextWatcher and the affected methods are 'afterTextChanged', 'beforeTextChanged', and 'onTextChanged'. Not sure if that helps but thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What version of java is on the mac and pc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this issue at work occasionally. Go to the project's properties, then go to Java Compiler and change the compiler compliance level to 1.6. That's what I set it to.

I think that setting must be workspace specfic because I can't get it to save in source control either.

EDIT: Also, the Android context menu for a project has "Fix Project Properties" which might also help. I don't know for sure if it does the fix I mention above, I don't use this option often.

Answer (score 2):

Between Java 5 and Java 6 changes to the specification of @Override have been made. In Java 6 it is possible to add the @Override annotation to methods that implement methods of an interface which is not allowed in Java 5.

So please check the compiler settings of the project, as you are compiling with Java 1.5 on one machine and with Java 6 on the other.